# "Excel found unreadable content" when opening a document that a macro was used in

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro many years ago and have used it once a month since then to automate a very lengthy process.

This month for some reason, with all data being the same, it failed miserably. But if I save the file after running the macro, and then try to open it again, I get the error message that Excel found unreadable data.

I'm self taught in VBA and not up on the technical jargon. So if someone could help me to understand why this is happening, and why my macro might be failing I'd sure appreciate it.

It is being used on a corporate system in a network where I do not have access to see the updates or background files.

Comment: The error means your file is corrupt. Try to save it in the binary format `xlsb` and see if it get's repaired. Sometimes this helps. • Also if you have issues with your code you need to include that code into your question ([edit]) otherwise we are unable to help you. • Also refer to: [How do I resolve the error “Excel found unreadable content in (filename)”?](https://superuser.com/questions/401714/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-excel-found-unreadable-content-in-filename)

Answer (score -2):

It's a hard one to answer as there could be so many things wrong.

I had a similar problem a while ago with a file that would have the same problem, the only solution I came up with was removing one item at a time from the file until the problem went away.
Alternatively, if you can access the macros and data, manually move them to a new workbook.